# Event specific methods are left dangling in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The two methods below are in the top scope of [backbone.js](http://www.backbonejs.org).  However they are only used in Backbone.Events.

Why weren't they included as a property in the object literal passed to Backbone.Events like the other methods were?

Was this to keep them private and out of the user API?

```
// only used in Backbone.Events
eventsApi = function(obj, action, name, rest) {
    // internals
};
// only used in Backbone.Events
triggerEvents = function(events, args) {
    // internals
};
```

Comment: Yes, they're for internal use. I don't see anywhere that those functions are exposed as part of the public API.

Answer (score 2):

> Was this to keep them private and out of the user API?

I'd say yes.  Its the revealing module pattern.

```
var myModule = (function() {
  var privateFn = function() { ... };

  return {
    publicFn: function() {
      return privateFn();
    }
  };
}());
```

Or using the terms via backbone:

```
(function(){

  // other backbone code

  var eventsApi = function() { ... };
  var Events = Backbone.Events = {
    on: function() {
      // code...
      var whatever = eventsApi(some, args);
      // code...
    }
  };

  // other backbone code

}());
```

Now `Events.Backbone.on` is a function which can call the function `eventsApi`, even though the `eventsApi` function is not exposed publicly.